# Find a path from $s$ to $t$ with smallest "bottleneck"

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science

> Let an undirected graph, $G=(V,E)$ with weights defined by the function $w:E\to\mathbb{N}$ and for each edge: $1\le w(e) \le |V|$. You are given two vertices: $s,t\in V$. Find a path from $s$ to $t$ where the maximum weight is minimal.

Basically I thought about utilizing DFS with a small modification:

We scan the graph from $s$ using DFS only we may add a vertex to the queue more than one time. We keep for each vertex a value $light[v]$. Now, consider a gray vertex, $v$ (meaning, a vertex which already scanned). Suppose there's an edge $\langle u,v\rangle$ such that $$w(u,v) < light[v]$$ then we update $light[v] = w(u,v)$ and insert $v$ to the queue once again.

I want to verify the correctness of my suggested algorithm. Also, is this linear? ($O(|V| +|E|$). I am not sure about that since basically each vertex could be added to the queue several times.

Comment: You're looking for a minimax path. The almost-identical problem of finding the maximin path is called the widest path problem. You can simultaneously find a minimax path for *all* pairs of vertices (assuming the graph is connected, which we can freely do by adjoining edges with infinite weight until the graph is complete) by finding a minimum spanning tree. That can be done in $O(|E| \log(|V|))$ time with Kruskal's algorithm. Then a minimax path is just any path between the two vertices in the minimum spanning tree.

Comment: @Ian, the algorithm should be efficient (I know it can be done in linear time)

Comment: Well, Wikipedia roughly sketches a linear time algorithm. The idea is that if you knew what the maximum edge weight in the minimax path was, then you would just cut out all edges of higher weight and then find any path between the two vertices using BFS or DFS.

Comment: So you can divide & conquer to find out what the maximum weight is, and build the path in the process: begin by cutting out all edges of higher weight than the median. If a path exists, then you recurse on the new graph with the deleted edges (since there might be a better path). If a path doesn't exist, then you can contract all edges of lower weight than the median and continue. I'm a bit surprised that this is apparently linear time, though (it seems like it would again be $O(|E| \log(|V|)$).

Comment: I think we should utilize the fact that the weight of any edge 
is bounded by $|V|$.

Comment: Are the weights all integers (so there can only be at most $|V|$ different weights)? (If not then this is just a normalization and has no real impact.)

Comment: Oh indeed. Let me fix that.

Comment: A related question: are the edges given to you sorted? Seeing as there's no general linear time sorting algorithm, that might be useful for getting a linear time algorithm. (I don't see how the algorithm I suggested could be linear otherwise.)

Comment: No, they aren't sorted.

Comment: If you succeed, and some edge in your path is not the lowest, then delete the edges in $U$ and recurse on the smaller graph (attempting to find a better path). If you fail, contract the edges in $L$ and recurse on the smaller graph (relaxing the constraint on your admissible paths). (Alternately, you can avoid contracting by simply taking a new partition, where $M'$ is the median of the edge weights in $U$, $L'$ is the edges less than the weight in $M$, and $U'$ is the edges greater than the weight in $M$.)

Comment: @Ian your idea is very similar to the one described in [this](https://opus4.kobv.de/opus4-zib/frontdoor/deliver/index/docId/916/file/ZR-06-22.pdf) paper, in section 2. However, I don't quite understand it because the pseudocode lacks details and uses some terms/notations in an adhoc manner. OP seems to be inactive on this site, but you're not; if you figured out a complete solution, would you mind posting it for completeness? I see only discussions in comments, with no conclusions drawn; it's a pity to leave things halfway after it looked like going somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can use a variant of Prim's Algorithm with the following modifications:

1. For each node $v$ you store the weight of a path with minimal maximum weight $d[v]$. Initially all these weights are set to $d[v] = \infty$ except for $d[s] = 0$.
2. Let's say now that the node with the *minimum cost* is $u$. For each neighbor $v_i$ of $u$ we should update the cost $c[v_i]$ and set the *maximum* weight $d[v_i]$ of the path so far.
3. To set the $maximum$ cost $c[v_i]$ first we check if $\max\{d[u], w(u,v_i)\} < d[v_i]$, and if true, update $d[v_i] = \max\{d[u], w(u,v_i)\}$.

Similar to [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848857/finding-an-mst-among-all-spanning-trees-with-maximum-of-white-edges/1849559#1849559), the algorithm can be implemented in linear time using a bucket queue.

Note that a single extract min operation might take $\mathcal{O}(\lvert V \rvert)$ here, in contrast to your other question. However, you can keep a pointer to the bucket corresponding to the minimum weight returned in the last operation. Then you either return the next element from the same bucket (if it is not yet empty) or you advance the pointer until you reach a non-empty bucket. In the end, the pointer will have iterated once over all buckets. Thus, the amortized cost for all extract min operations is $\mathcal{O}(\lvert V \rvert)$.

Comment: Did you mean that the initial weights are minus infinity ? Because the max of inf and a value is always inf. I am missing something?